# Undefined references when mixing gfortran and g++ compilation

Tags: c++, fortran, g++, gfortran, linker-errors

I am trying to mix Fortran and C++ object files, which are perfectly working and producing executable with a simple C++ file. However, when I am trying to mix the same Fortran object file with the main C++ code (which is a very large and complicated code) it is producing following errors listed below. I have played with the positions of `-lgfortran` but no luck.

The command used is

```
g++ -o test *.o  -static -lpthread -L/usr/local/lib -lquadmath -lgfortran
```

and all kind of permutations are also have been tried.

Errors are:

```
gcc_4_9_2_release/libgfortran/io/write_float.def:1300: undefined reference to `signbitq'
gcc_4_9_2_release/libgfortran/io/write_float.def:1300: undefined reference to `finiteq'
gcc_4_9_2_release/libgfortran/io/write_float.def:1213: undefined reference to `finiteq'
gcc_4_9_2_release/libgfortran/io/write_float.def:1300: undefined reference to `isnanq'
```

Comment: Gfortran 4.9 would work with gcc and g++ 4.9 but not with dissimilar compilers.

Comment: gfortran and g++ are having same version, 4.9 and it is working with a simple example code.

Comment: You should show the command which causes the error messages. Also you should try to isolate a small example.

Comment: g++ -lpthread  -static -o test *.o -lquadmath -lgfortran  -lpthread  -static

Comment: Why 2x -static? Why 2x -lpthread? The order of the libraries does matter when using static linking.

Comment: I have tried all combinations, before and after. After getting frustrated I used in both ends but error remains same.

Comment: Now, it is working with the following command. "g++ -static -o test *.o -lgfortran -lpthread -L/usr/local/lib -lquadmath". Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Working command is

```
      g++ -static -o test *.o -lgfortran -lpthread -L/usr/local/lib -lquadmath
```

Answer (score 0):

'nm' both the c.o and the fortran.o
I am guessing it is probably an underscore you need.

Comment: That's most unlikely given the symbols come from the C-based libquadmath. Actually, you can easily notice that the OP has found the solution already. He has already answered his question. This should really have been a comment.